# question about POST and redirect

Tags: php, forms, post

So I have a html form and I have an URL where it will be submitted, say the URL is www.myformsubmit.com/form_submit.php. This form_submit.php will give me a text saying if everything is correct in the form or prints out an error message.

What I want to do is that to do is that after the form is submitted to form_submit.php I want to redirect users to a thank you page. My question, is there a way to do this without having to touch the form_submit.php, if yes how?

Comment: `is there a way to do this without having to touch the form_submit.php` There is no way of doing it without touching or replacing the file because A) it would never know when to redirect since it can't touch the file B) it needs 1 line added to it so it redirects to your thankyou page. Using AJAX what you could do is instead of using your html page to send the data to the php file you would use the AJAX to deal that data for you, and doing so you would be able to filter the response and/or redirect your users.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot modify for form_submit.php? Without using PHP's header instruction the only way would be to use javascript/jQuery as explained below.

Comment: I think I like using the AJAX way..

Comment: What do you mean "touch" and "give me a text"? Do you *only* mean that you don't want the user to see it in the address bar? If so, I think your question may be misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

With your current setup, you can't redirect to another page without modifying `form_submit.php`.

**You *can* have the form submit to itself,** and then do something like this:

```
<?php
    // Optionally, also make sure that there are no errors.
    if (isset($_POST["SomeInputValue"])):
    {
        // Must be BEFORE any output is sent!
        header("Location: /thank_you.php");
    }

    else
    {
        // Display the form page.
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question, is there a way to do this without having to touch the form_submit.php, if yes how?

You want to check if everything is fine from form_submit.php but you do not want to post data to it? I think this is really not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to do this without having to touch the form_submit.php,
>   if yes how?

The short answer would be no. To correctly answer your question we need to know why you cannot modify form_submit.php. This is because a simple line of code could be added to redirect to a "thank you" page when the form is correctly filled in.

(Will edit this accordingly as the question is developped)

Comment: It's a PHP question. OP needs to understand the basics before doing anything like this.

Comment: I've added a PHP snippet. I'm not sure it would work though as, thinking of it now, curl would be equivalent to a redirect. I've also added some tutorial links in case using clientside javascript turns out to be the only viable option.

Comment: Per your edit: Once again, I think the OP has misunderstood something very basic. I don't think throwing cURL and ajax at this simple problem is a good solution. Seriously - would ***you*** use this code? Unless you think this is a challenge for curiosity's sake, it would be more helpful to guide OP in the right direction. It's not your fault the question is so poorly communicated, but I believe it's fairly clear that OP is still learning the fundamentals.

Comment: Honestly? I would not :) . I think you're right in trying to get to the root of the problem. It isn't clear why `form_submit.php` can't be modified and what the objective is. From what I can understand, `form_submit.php` outputs an AOK or errors. I assume that the idea is to redirect to a "thank you" page when the form is correctly filled in.

Comment: Edited my answer for the time being and will only add some hocus pocus if necessary ;)